# Derivative of a PDF w.r.t. to its paramters

Tags: probability, probability-theory, derivatives, density-function

I want to calculate the derivative of a density function with respect to its parameters. In my case the density is given by:
$$
p( x | y )= \int p( x | y, z ) p( z | y ) ~dz
$$
where $ z|y\sim \mathcal{N}( \mu(\theta,y), \sigma(\theta,y) ) $ and $\theta$ is a constant parameter.

I'm looking for the derivative of $p( x | y )$ with respect to $\theta$
$$
d/d\theta~p( x | y ) = d/d\theta \left( \int p( x | y, z ) p( z | y ) ~dz \right)
$$
My approach was as follows (using chain rule):
$$
d/d\theta~p( x | y ) = d/dz \left( \int p( x | y, z ) p( z | y ) ~dz \right)  \cdot dz/d\theta  
$$

but left me with $dz/d\theta $ which I don't know how to interpret and therefore made me questioning the full approach. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure why you want a chain rule here; at least the variable $z$ is already integrated out and the resulting conditional pdf $p(x|y)$ should be functionally independent of $z$

Comment: @BGM thanks for you comment. That also came into my mind, but I thought using chain rule would be a convenient trick (because computing $p(x|y)$ via the integral would be difficult in some cases). In any case, could you tell me what is conceptually wrong with my approach?